# Fix php script to replace some HTML elements using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have a problem with a PHP script using the class `DOMDocument`. I need to fix an HTML document that it comes with some elements inside of Span tags, so i have to change that spans for divs, example:

```
<span class="example1">Some text <div>whatever...</div></span>
```

the result should be:

```
<div class="example1">Some text <div>whatever...</div></div>
```

My PHP file:

```
$html = '<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <span class="class_1">Example 1</span>
        <span class="class_2">Example 2<span class="class_3">Example 3</span></span>
        <span class="class_4">Example 4</span>
        <span class="class_5">Example 5<span class="class_6">Example 6<span class="class_7">Example 7</span></span></span>
        <div><span class="class_8">Example 8</span></div>
    </body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$innerHTML = '';
$oldname = 'span';
$newname = 'div';

$element = $dom->getElementsByTagName($oldname);

for($i=0;$i< $element->length ;$i++){
    $node = $element->item($i); 
    while ($node->hasChildNodes() ) {
        $child = $node->childNodes->item(0);
        $newTag =  $child->nodeType == 1 ? $newname : $oldname;                       
        $newNode = $node->ownerDocument->createElement($newTag);
        $child = $node->ownerDocument->importNode($child, true);
        $newNode->appendChild($child);
    }
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        $attrName = $attr->nodeName;
        $attrValue = $attr->nodeValue;
        $newNode->setAttribute($attrName, $attrValue);
    }
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);    
}
$innerHTML .= $dom->saveXML();
echo $innerHTML;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head/><body>
            <span class="class_1">Example 1</span>
            <div class="class_2"><span class="class_3">Example 3</span></div>
            <span class="class_4">Example 4</span>
            <div class="class_5"><span class="class_6">Example 6<span class="class_7">Example 7</span></span></div>
            <div><span class="class_8">Example 8</span></div>
        </body></html>
```

Here i have 2 problems:

1) The first one is that the span with the class "class_6" should be a Div because it has a child element, but it's not replacing it.

2) The second one is the text is missing when it's replaced for a div, for example in div class = "class_2" dissapeared the text "Example 2".

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st one is that you should change your for loop to this `for($i=1;$i<= $element->length ;$i++)`. The length of elements (if they are not empty) starts from 1 not 0. That means that you start your loop at 0 (where nothing happens) and you finish at 5 because you have `$i < $element->length`. By changing this, you will start at 1 where you have your first item and finish when `$i` is equal to `$element->length`.

The 2nd one, is that you change the `span` to `div` and then within the `div` you `append` the value of the child. By this way you override the inner value of your previously `span` element. Consinder of appending the previously value of the span element + the value of the child, as the append value of the new div element.

Hope that solution helps!

Comment: That seems logical, i'll try it!

Comment: Give us your feedback after that :)